# Odoo 9 show user its default POS

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I need to show user its own assigned POS. I mean, I need to hide other POS on POS dashboard. Consider following example

There are three users

user 1, user 2 and user 3

and there are three POSs

POS 1, POS 2, POS 3

Now

User 1 has rights to access POS 1, and User 1 should not be able to access otherusers  POS's

User 2 has rights to access POS 2, and User 2 should not be able to access other users POS's

User 3 has rights to access POS 3, and User 3 should not be able to access other users POS's

Please help me in that

Comment: You can add a filter domain on the field config_id of possession for a new field like "user_id" (add it on pos.config).
Not sure if pos of 9 is same than 8.

Comment: am not clear, how can i do that ?

Comment: - Add field on pos.config model called user_id
- Add a domain on the view of pos.session with the field pos_config (from a py if possible)

Then in the domain function you can get the user id from the context and return that id

Comment: and then after that ?

Comment: Sorry, edited my question accidentaly sent, check now

Comment: Sir actually i am totally new to odoo, i know what models are but am not familiar with odoo filters, odoo domains, and odoo sessions. Could you please explain your answer in detail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104420/discussion-between-ahmed-khakwani-and-dccdany).

Answer (score 1):

pos.config model:

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', "User")
```

Add this field on the view, here is where u choose the user that will have access to that configuration (Configuration > Points of sale)

pos.session model:

```
config_id = fields.Many2one('pos.config', 'Point of Sale',
                                  help="The physical point of sale you   will use.",
                                  required=True,
                                  select=1,
                                  domain = _get_pos_config_domain)

def _get_pos_config_domain(self):

    pos_config_ids = self.env['pos.config'].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.context.uid)])

    domain = [('state', '=', 'active'), ('id', 'in', pos_config_ids)]

    return domain
```